# Cannot run InstallShield application as administrator on Windows 7

Tags: windows, admin, installshield

I have installed InstallShield while logged it as the Administrator on Windows 7.  "Run as Administrator" is missing from the right-click pop-up menu for InstallShield but is there for Visual Studio and other applications.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: What's the problem here - can you not start InstallShield as administrator just by launching it normally?

Answer (score 1):

Applications that contain [certain keys words](http://www.isosoft.org/taoffi/post/2010/06/09/Windows-Vista-Windows-7-To-pin-or-not-to-pin-that-ise280a6.aspx) are prevented from pinning by the OS. [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/68ed3447-7570-4245-b336-6bd0c69966d7) is another discussion about this limitation.

Comment: The problem was that I was unable to start InstallShield as Administrator. The menu item "Run as Administrator" was missing from my right-click menu for the InstallShield application. "Run as Administrator" is present for other applications.  You must run as Administrator to be able to Download merge modules.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: In Windows 7 Ultimate, some application short have the "Run as Administrator" item in their context-menus and other applications do not.

"Run as Administrator" is required to use the "Download Selected Item" or "Download all items..." menu items on the Redistributables page in InstallShield.

This is the solution that seemed to work for me:

1. Right-click the shortcut on your desktop.
2. Click the "Troubleshoot Compatibility" item from the context menu.
3. After "Detecting issues" has run, select the "Troubleshoot program" option.
4. Check the "The program requires additional permissions" item and click the 
   "Next" button.
5. Click "Start the program..." and check the functionality.
6. If satisfied click "Next" on "Program Compatibility" dialog.
7. Click the "Yes, save these settings for this program."

If there are alternative solutions, would you share them?